# onclick event on List of buttons is not working using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, html-lists

I am trying to add events on my buttons inside a list, but it appears that only the first button on the list is being registered with an onclick event. There are no errors shown, but I don't get why only the first part of the button is being registered with an event? Here it is:

```
<ul id = "button-list"> 
    <li>
        <button class = "buttons" id = "first"  name = "ltrContainer"   ></button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class = "buttons" id = "second" name = "ltrContainer"  ></button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class = "buttons" id = "third"  name = "ltrContainer"   ></button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class = "buttons" id = "fourth" name = "ltrContainer"  ></button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class = "buttons" id = "fifth" name = "ltrContainer"  ></button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class = "buttons" id = "sixth" name = "ltrContainer"   ></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

only the first button is being registered with an event and here is my JQuery code

```
$('.buttons').click(function(){
    textContainer.value += this.innerHTML;
    alert(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: Seems to work for me - http://jsfiddle.net/s9JhF/

Comment: try checking the console for errors

Comment: I am using firefox with firebug

Comment: @user962206 worked for me as well for all buttons

Comment: Why is it working on mine, there are no errors shown in my console.

Comment: I added my whole code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ra9ne/2/

Comment: before asking a question write your `undefined functions` and clarify the issue properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(function(){
    $('.buttons"').click(function(){
            var myValue = $(this).html();
            alert(myValue); 
        });
      });
 });
```

I hop this will help

Answer (score 2):

Thery are no value in inner html of buttons. you will write any value in buttons.
I have modify your code check it

```
<ul id = "button-list"> 
    <li>
        <button class = "buttons" id = "first"  name = "ltrContainer"   >1</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class = "buttons" id = "second" name = "ltrContainer"  >2</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class = "buttons" id = "third"  name = "ltrContainer"   >3</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class = "buttons" id = "fourth" name = "ltrContainer"  >4</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class = "buttons" id = "fifth" name = "ltrContainer"  >5</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class = "buttons" id = "sixth" name = "ltrContainer"   >6</button>
    </li>
</ul>



$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $('.buttons').click(function(){
    document.getElementById('textContainer').value += this.innerHTML;
    alert(this.innerHTML);
    });
});
```

Comment: but I am filling it its value from the XML that I am getting

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button-list .buttons").each(function () {
            $(this).bind("click", function() {
                //Put your code here
            });
});
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I agree kommradHome. Also raheel code also looks fine. Using click sometime not working in IE7 (I faced it :( ). It is advisable to use bind instead of click which also work fine with IE7. If not considering IE7 then no problem. ;)